# Is it breaking Facade design pattern

Tags: list, arrays, design-patterns, facade

In HomeCADEngine facade class I have a method "addRoom(room:Room)" and it will add this room to a ArrayList. But is it break facade pattern when we create a room outside facade class and then pass it into addRom() method??

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends, the patterns are only guidelines to improve your code. In this case, it would be more accurate if you create the Room inside the facade and you cannot access to the Room class from any other class except from the facade class, even for creating a new instance of Room.

The important thing is that the purpose of the facade pattern is to encapsulate all the acceses to other/s classes and every access to them must be through the facade class.

Answer (score 0):

The design patterns are considered only as examples how in certain situations the design can be improved. You should never use the design patterns as they are. You always have to think, what exactly helps you in your specific situation.
The reason why the design patterns like facade are so common is that it is observered in practice that the situation in which exactly a facade is helpful, occurs relatively often. So it makes sense to to illustrate it as a common pattern, so that everybody has some sort of inspiration when defining an own design.

That means, it is not the facade that makes your design good. The facade is not an official good solution. What a good design is depends only on your situation. You may pick a design that is very close to a facade. Then you could even say it is facade, because that is what everybody understands, or you say it is "like a facade" or you name it completely different.

Let us see what I mean:
Consider for example you have a class CadObject. You think, you want to have a facade for it. And you think, a facade is something official that you should implement in an official way. So you call your facade CadObjectFacade. Unfortunately then you are on a wrong path. Because the name CadObjectFacade is not appropriate. A facade is the front of a building. Why do you name your class like the front of a building? The fact that it uses a facade design pattern is just an implementation detail. You should name your classes according to the functions they are providing but not according to implementation details. If your facade for example is a comfortable way of working with the geometry of a CadObject, then your facade should better be named CadObjectGeometry. Or if your facade is a comfortable way of working with the materials of a CadObject or the price, your facade should better be named CadObjectMaterials or CadOjectPricing.

You may say that these names do not help the reader of the code to understand the design. The reader should rather see that it is a facade. That concern is wrong. If a facade is an appropriate solution, then it must be also intuitive to use a facade (something not intuitive cannot be appropriate). But if a facade is intuitive and natural, you don't have to explicitly name it a facade. You does also do not name your classes CadObjectClass, PositionClass, RectangleClass. The way how it must be intuitively clear that CadObject, Position, Rectangle are classes, it must also be intuitive that you use a facade or another design pattern. And if it is intuitive to do something outside the facade and the coupling and the cohesion are ok, then such design is also good.

You see, when using a facade design, there is no right and wrong. It depends on your situation. If you ask if you can create a room outside your facade, then you should also ask yourself why this should be a problem? With a facade you typically intend to simplify some things. If you think you want to simplify the room creation, then include it to the facade. If not then not. But this question depends on what you think makes the usage easy and what you think should be abstract. You can also have another facade for the room creation, or a wrapper or a strategy.